# Is the Mandelbrot set weakly self-similar?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, euclidean-geometry, fractals, complex-dynamics, self-similarity

A subset $F$ of an [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) $E$ will be called *weakly self-similar* if for all $x \in F$ there is $\epsilon_x>0$ such that for all positive $\epsilon \le \epsilon_x$ there are  $y \in F$, $\epsilon' \ge \epsilon_x$ and a [similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#In_Euclidean_space) $s$ of $E$ such that $$s(F \cap B(y,\epsilon')) = F \cap B(x,\epsilon) $$ with $B(z,r)$ the ball of center $z$ and radius $r$.

*Question*: Is the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) weakly self-similar?

If so: Is there $\alpha>0$ such that for all $x \in F$, we can take $\epsilon_x>\alpha ?$

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier: in the definition written, *weakly self-similar* does *not* main self-similar with a weak similarity (sorry for the confusion). If $\epsilon < \epsilon_x$ then $\epsilon < \epsilon'$, and so $s$ is not an isometry.

Comment: Sorry, there is no confusion in your definition, I should have seen that the part around $y$ is required to be bigger. Thank you to have pointed to it.